# How to put subviews in the correct place for different screens

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uikit, autolayout

I am developing a `ViewController` with some UI elements as `SubViews` but I have problems with these elements when I run the app on different devices. I am doing everything by code. Should I use `AutoLayout`? How should I use autolayout for this elements?

[image: iphone5 (4 inches)]

[image: iphone 4 (3.5 inches)]

I have these items :

```
    titleLbl = [[WPCustomLabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, self.view.frame.size.height/2, 260, 25)];
    [titleLbl setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:18]];
    [self.view addSubview:titleLbl];

    NSLog(@"%f", self.view.bounds.size.height/2);


    textLbl = [[WPCustomLabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40, self.view.frame.size.width/2 + 10, 250, 230)];
    [textLbl setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentJustified];
    [self.view addSubview:textLbl];


    omitBtn = [[WPCustomButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.bounds.size.height-108 , self.view.bounds.size.width/2, 44)];
    [omitBtn setTitle:@"Omitir" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [omitBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(omitInfo) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:omitBtn];


    nextBtn = [[WPCustomButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2, self.view.frame.size.height-108, self.view.frame.size.width/2, 44)];
    [nextBtn setTitle:@"Siguiente" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [nextBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(omitInfo) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:nextBtn];
```

Comment: Have you tried storyboard with AutoLaoyouts ?

Comment: I do not use storyboards..

Comment: Override the `viewWillLayoutSubviews` method and update the frames as needed based on the frame of `self.view`.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using storyboards then yes, you should use autolayout. Just set a constraint between the labels and the bottom of the superview.

[image]

If you are not using storyboards, you can override `viewWillLayoutSubviews` and set the layout depending on the size of your view.

Answer (score -2):

personally i give advice to don't  use auto layout but used this code

```
if ([UIDevice currentDevice].userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
    if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 480) {
        //iPhone 4
    }else{
        //iPhone 
    }
}else{
    //iPad
}
```

this code into separately define All object frame.

Comment: You prefer to use this code changing the frame position, don't you?

Comment: ya, i m define the frame for 4 and 5.at my point of view auto layout create some time problem in lower iOS version. so, i prefer that..

Comment: I target iOS 6 and iOS7. I guess I will try to do it like you say